# 3 column with equal margin

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/zfacazy0/

```css
.row {
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.col{
  width:30%;
  margin-right:5px;
  background:red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">1</div>
<div class="col">2</div>
<div class="col" style="margin-right:0">3</div>
</div>
```

if I put 33% and the margin is too much it will not have single row. Either I adjust margin or width, I just can't do a proper 3 column with equal margin and width. Need help.

Comment: give the margin in %

Comment: there are a couple of resources out there where you can learn on how to calculate your px into %, this is just a random one, hope it helps :) http://resources.sameerast.com/responsive-web-design-formula-easy-calculator.html

Answer (score 2):

Check this. You can use the `first-child` attribute to remove margin from first element.

```css
.row {
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.col {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
.col:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why 30% of width can fit 5% of margin? how is the calculation is done? If I put 32%, to be fitted I have to use 2% of margin-left.

Comment: Yes, You are right! Eg. 100% - (32+32+32)% = 96%. So remaining 4%(2+2) as margin

Answer (score 1):

Just `display:flex` can do the trick:

```css
.row {
  width:200px;
  background:blue;
  display:flex;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.col{
  width:33%;
  margin-right:5px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">1</div>
<div class="col">2</div>
<div class="col" style="margin-right:0">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jennifer you can learn it here with good description. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ It will useful in many place and design your layout easily

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .row {
        width: 200px;
        background: blue;
        display: flex;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .col {
        width: 33.33%;
        margin-right: 5px;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">1</div>
<div class="col">2</div>
<div class="col" style="margin-right:0">3</div>
</div>
```